# How can I go through different dictionaries using nested loop?

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, for-loop, nested-loops

```
sem1_credit = {'A': 4, 'B': 4, 'C': 3}
sem2_credit = {'D': 5, 'E': 1}
sem3_credit = {'F': 3}
e = 2 
for j in range(e):
        for i in 'sem'+str(j+1)+'_credit':
```

I wanted to use loop to access different dict. So I tried to create the dict name with concatenation using loop. But it doesn't work. Is there a way to work it out or is there some other way to approach dict without loops.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get a dictionary of the current local symbols table by calling `locals()`. So `locals()['sem1_credit']` is essentially this `sem1_credit`.

From here, you can build a loop:

```py
sem1_credit = {'A': 4, 'B': 4, 'C': 3}
sem2_credit = {'D': 5, 'E': 1}
sem3_credit = {'F': 3}
 
for idx in range(1, 4):
    credits = locals()[f'sem{idx}_credit']
    for key, credit in credits.items():
        print(f"{key} {credit}")
```

Keep in mind that the `range(num)` generate numbers from 0 to num-1. So in your code, `range(2)` only generates 0 and 1.